# Create Openshift app using branch from existing repository (with `rhc create`)

Tags: git, openshift, git-branch, openshift-client-tools, openshift-web-console

The OpenShift web console allows to create a new app using a branch/tag from an existing remote repository which I do not know how to use through `rhc create`.

The relevant command line option `--from-code URL` works great for the default repository path, **but how to tell which specific branch to use?** I can't find anything at the [OpenShift documentation](https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-creating-applications.html) or any other web resource.

I tried the following and some other variants, but without success:

`rhc app create my_new_app_name python-3.3 postgresql-9.2 --from-code https://github.com/my_user/my_repository/tree/my_branch`

`rhc app create my_new_app_name python-3.3 postgresql-9.2 --from-code https://github.com/my_user/my_repository.git/my_branch`

The resulting message:

`Source code repository could not be cloned: 'https://github.com/my_user/my_repository.git/my_branch'. Please verify the repository is correct and contact support.`

I need to use `rhc create` to create the new app, because this allows app creation with more than one cartridge (here `python-3.3` and `postgresql-9.2`), which is not possible through the web console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close. You can create your application from a branch by doing the following:

`rhc app create my_new_app_name python-3.3 postgresql-9.2 --from-code https://github.com/my_user/my_repository#mybranch`